# Cucumber + Selenium got Error when try to import Cucumber

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, cucumber

I got this error when I trying to using cucumber and selenium.

Any advice please? Please refer below for my code and the error.

Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to add the cucumber package...

Comment: @MosheSlavin then after download i need to import that?

Comment: yup! see: https://www.toolsqa.com/cucumber/install-cucumber-eclipse-plugin/

Comment: @MosheSlavin I've checked. But they said already installed.

Comment: Show/Edit into your question... the details in the problems tab...

Comment: @MosheSlavin updated. u can see the picture now. Already installed. Any advice?

Comment: as I have comented... you should show the errors that are in the Problems tab... please add the text not a pic...

Comment: @MosheSlavin done. u can check now

Comment: see: https://www.toddlahman.com/import-org-junit-cannot-resolved-eclipse/

Comment: see: https://docs.cucumber.io/installation/java/

Comment: Have u added the cucumber jars in the POM? If the scope of the cucumber jars is set to 'test', it wont work as ur code is in src/main/java where by convention it should be in src/test/java.

Comment: @MosheSlavin still got error

Comment: @Grasshopper so, u mean need to create class java in src/test/java?

Comment: If the cucumber jars have scope set to 'test' in POM then those jars will only be available in the src/test/java folder.